# Making 2 characters fall on love

Tags: characters

So I’ve been working on this story for almost 3 years now but I always start over because  my ideas change over time . This time tho , the protagonists changed a lot from the original idea . So here’s the problem . 
The female is more of a crazy type , she’s a drug addict and she’s the typical maniac character that can throw a knife into someone’s head out of boredom . 
And the male ...he has some trust issues and frustrations . He hates being controlled and hates being “like a loser” to say . 
The issue is that the female will be a bitch to him , it’s just the way she is . Playing mind games , cursing him , making rude remarks .. 
Because of that he’ll just give up of trying to befriend her “screw it” . Idk how good i explained . You get the idea , their personalities are stopping them from being together. 
He will get angry cause she treats him like trash , and she? She’s bored . 
So how can I make them fall in love ?

Comment: Everybody has layers. And usually, the things you see out of someone on the surface are compensations for characteristics wildly different or even opposite of what they pretend to be. If they actually get to know each other, maybe the girl is relatable to the guy, or they have more in common than they thought. They can change. And also - opposites attract, right?

Comment: make a list of how they behave AFTER they've fallen in love. Right now you have a drug addict throwing knives at a loser…. It's a lot easier to build a road when you know where it's going…. If you don't want them to fix their personalities, you can always use the old standby: sexual attraction.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have more control on the guy then the girl. Therefore, I would suggest that the girl might face something that makes her life turns 180 degrees to a different person - like a loss from someone she cares, or perhaps losing her memories. She then starts to slow down on her lifestyle and began to realize that she needs to stop and see the things around her. On the other side, the guy, realize this and starts to take care of the girl that they fall in love between each other.

Comment: Welcome to writing SE. I'm not the one who downvoted you, but just to explain, we discourage answering questions that don't follow writing [SE guidelines](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for what is on topic here. This question is essentially asking what to write.